# checking gpu for VBO existence

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

I got a (pre-made) Opengl vertex buffer object `(VBO)`
but I don't know it's `GLuint`  value to submit it in opencl ..

is there a check in any opengl library (like glew) to give me existing VBOs and its corresponding  GLuint that are currently on the gpu (or anything similar..as only thing i know about data inputs is number of elements in the array and array size)

edit:
why i don't know GLuint ...

it's a function in cinema4d opengl api (have to use this function to access cinema4d VBO) ..this function(or i should say alot of class functions) are automatically doing something like this

allocSubBuffer ...with *pBuffer (object oriented C++)
mapBuffer ..returns void *pData
then cast this *pData to a vector *pvData
then pass the array values to that *pvData
then unmapbuffer...
after this there's something called pFactory...it assigns automatically a new VBO ...

Comment: not sure, but there might not be one. just maybe with glGet

Comment: "any opengl library (like glew)" OpenGL is a API specification, not a specific library. GLEW is just a wrapper to make extended functionality of the OpenGL API easier to access.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know it's GLuint value

Then how do you use the VBO from OpenGL? You have to `glBindBuffer` it in OpenGL as well. OpenGL object IDs are precious, keep them close, and keep them safe.

Creating a OpenGL object without remembering its name is like allocating some memory with `new` or `malloc` and then throwing away the pointer: A waste of memory.

Comment: @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf: Well in that case you can't be even sure that there is a VBO at all. By the looks of it, all you do is passing some data to Cinema4D which it will keep around in its internal structures and *maybe* it uses it for a VBO, but it as well might not, or merge it with other data into a single large VBO. But why do you care anyway? Just create your own VBO or pass the data to OpenCL using the OpenCL APIs for that.

Comment: well i want to do a realtime fluid simulation
the main bottleneck in this kind of simulations is memory transfer speed...i can do it in opencl..transfer to cpu,,but frame rates will drop dramatically...wanted to use the opengl VBO for faster access of data

Comment: @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf: It's very likely that Cinema4D is using that data not only on the GPU side for rendering, but also on the CPU side for other things. So the data will go through the CPU←→GPU bottleneck one way or another. The mere fact that you hand Cinema4D a buffer on the CPU side should be indicative enough. Here's my suggestion: Do your fluid simulation on the GPU, using OpenCL, read back the results, hand it over to Cinema4D and let that one do its thing. You don't know what's going on in that black box behind the API, don't try to outsmart it.

Comment: @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf: That additional GPU→CPU→GPU roundtrip for the rendering data is a bullet you'll have to bite, until the developers of Cinema4D actually provide a sane interface for GPU API interoperation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &buf) will do the trick for you. I.e. you force somehow cinema4d to bind the buffer and then query for currently bound buffer ID.

Comment: The problem is, that you don't really know if there's a VBO used by Cinema4D at all. And if it does, if the buffer contains just that data, or if it has been multiplexed or put inbetween other data. Cinema4D is a black box in that regard and should be treated as such.

Comment: I suppose there is no good (universal) solution to this problem at all. So we have dilemma: no solution at all or dirty hack. So this is dirty hack, but who cares if it'll get things done.